# Opportunity Currency field editable for single user

Tags: opportunity

I want to display Opportunity Currency field only for single user in my org. So that the user can modify currency. I know it is possible by creating different profile with page layout. Any other suggestions on this will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [permission sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)? You can hide a field from the profile (and in turn it makes the field inaccessible from page layout as well), and add access to a field using permission set and assign it to targeted users without impacting the profile.

Comment: I tried with above solution but the opportunity currency field is not editable in Profiles. So i can not remove the accessibility from profiles.